How can I get a certain number of evenly spaced points along the octagon perimeter?
I want to get the coordinates of a number of points that together form an octagon.
For a circle this is done easily as follows:
import numpy as np

n = 100
x = np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n))
y = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n))

coordinates = list(zip(x, y))

By changing n I can increase/decrease the "angularity". Now I want to do the same for an octagon. I know that an octagon has 8 sides and the angle between each side 45 degrees.
Let's assume that the perimeter of the octagon is 30.72m. Each side has therefore a length of 3.79m.
perimeter = 30.72
n_sides = 8
angle = 45

How can I get n coordinates that represent this octagon?
Edit:
With the help of the answers of @lastchance and @mozway I am able to generate an octagon. My goal is to get evenly-spaced n coordinates from the perimeter of this octagon.
If n = 8 these coordinates correspond to the corners of the octagon, but I'm interested in cases where n > 8

Isn't that just 8? (well, with your linspace boundaries, 9, since you include 2π, that is the same as the first, either because you just forgot the 4th parameter of linspace, or because you did this voluntarily to close the loop). I am probably saying something stupid, but your question does not explain why, since you already did everthing needed, you don't just do exactly what you did, with n=8+1

Or is your question about the radius?

Define evenly spaced. If it's along the actual edges of the octagon, that's trivial: calculate perimeter, divide it into the desired number of segments, and then generate the points along the perimeter, progressively walking along the actual edges. If it's in the Euclidean sense, that feels being a lot more complicated.

As @tevemadar asks: what does "evenly spaced" mean: do you mean equal distance between points along the perimeter (which is fairly simple once you've generated your n-gon vertices and have your total perimeter length)? Equal angles wrt the center (easiest using line/line intersection)? Equal distance between point pairs in 2D space (quite the chore)? Something else?

Let's use some math.

Each triangle in the polygon is isosceles. Assuming r the radius of the containing circle and a each side of the polygon we have:
n_sides = 8
perimeter = n_sides * a
a/2 = sin(pi/n_sides) / r # isosceles = 2 equal right triangles
perimeter = n_sides * 2 * sin(pi/n_sides) / r
r =  perimeter/(2 * n_sides * sin(pi/n_sides))

Thus, the coordinates are:
perimeter = 30.72
n_sides = 8

r = perimeter/(2 * n_sides * np.sin(np.pi/n_sides))
x = r * np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_sides, endpoint=False))
y = r * np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_sides, endpoint=False))

Note the endpoint=False in linspace.
As a graph:
ax = plt.subplot(aspect=1)
ax.plot(x, y, marker='o')

Output:

If you want one extra point to "close" the polygon (the last point being the same as the first point):
x = r * np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_sides+1))
y = r * np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_sides+1))


Now, let's use shapely to check that the calculation is correct:
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

Polygon(zip(x, y)).length # 30.72


Interpolating n points on the octagon/polygon
Now that we have a polygon, we can interpolate n points along its perimeter.
Let's generate a "closed" polygon (i.e. n_sides+1 point in which the last one is equal to the first), create a LineString and interpolate n values along it:
from shapely.geometry import LineString

perimeter = 30.72
n_sides = 8
n = 12

# compute the points of the polygon
r = perimeter/(2 * n_sides * np.sin(np.pi/n_sides))
x = r * np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_sides+1))
y = r * np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_sides+1))

# create a line string
# interpolate n points on the perimeter
line = LineString(zip(x, y))

coords = np.concatenate(list(line.interpolate(x).coords
                             for x in np.linspace(0, line.length, n,
                                                  endpoint=False)))

# plot
ax = plt.subplot(aspect=1)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.plot(*coords.T, ls='', marker='o', label='n = 8')

Alternatively, performing the interpolation with numpy.interp:
perimeter = 30.72
n_sides = 8
n = 12

# compute the points of the polygon
r = perimeter/(2 * n_sides * np.sin(np.pi/n_sides))
x = r * np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_sides+1))
y = r * np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_sides+1))

# interpolate the n points along the perimeter
ref = np.linspace(0, 1, n_sides+1)*perimeter # distance to origin: ref
dist = np.linspace(0, 1, n+1)*perimeter      # distance to origin: n points
new_x = np.interp(dist, ref, x)   # interpolated x
new_y = np.interp(dist, ref, y)   # interpolated y

ax = plt.subplot(aspect=1)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.plot(new_x, new_y, ls='', marker='o')

Output:


The issue here as I understand it is that the question asks for N (not equal to 8) points along the octagon. e.g. for 16 points, subdividing each line segment in the middle. Unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

@Kaia that's a fair point, I really hadn't seen the question this way. Then OP should clarify and give an example of the expected output.

@Kaia Yes, that's indeed my intention. I will make my question more clear.

@HJA24 got it, thanks for clarifying. I updated the answer to show how to (1) generate the polygon, (2) find n equidistant points along its perimeter. Let me know if this it what you expected.

Well if you set n=8 and use your code for a circle, you will receive coordinates for an octagon. You then need to scale that octagon to meet your perimeter. I've added a distance function to help calculate the size of the edges of the original octogan. Also there is a rounding to 4 decimal places to make it more readable, but you may choose to remove that. I believe this will work for a shape of any size and any desired perimeter.
import numpy as np
    
def distance(coords1, coords2):
    return ((coords1[0] - coords2[0])**2 + (coords1[1] - coords2[1])**2 )**0.5

n = 8
target_perimeter = 30.72
x = np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n+1))
y = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n+1))

coordinates = list(zip(x, y))
perimeter = n * distance(coordinates[0], coordinates[1])
scaling_factor = target_perimeter / perimeter
scaled_coordinates = scaling_factor * np.array(coordinates)
print(scaled_coordinates.round(4))


The 1st and last point are the same here so you need n = 9 in the linspace function.

Another use for complex numbers. Your plot is an Argand diagram, with x and y coordinates the real and imaginary parts of a complex variable in polar form.
Part 1: Simple Octagon
It goes against the grain for my octagons to have 9 vertices, so I have used endpoint=False in the numpy.linspace call. To close the polygon I then simply join up last and first points with a separate plot call.
If you don't want octagons then change to whatever value of numsides you like.
from math import pi, sin
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

perimeter = 30.72
numsides = 8

radius = perimeter / ( 2 * numsides * sin( pi / numsides ) )
start = 0.5 / numsides         # or just 0
z = radius * np.exp( 2j * pi * ( np.linspace( 0, 1, numsides, endpoint=False ) + start ) )
x, y = z.real, z.imag
plt.plot( x, y, 'r-', marker='o' );   plt.plot( [x[-1],x[0]], [y[-1],y[0]], 'r-' )
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()


Part 2: Additional Points
It's not quite clear what "evenly-spaced" means: it could mean equally distributed by perimetric distance, or it could mean equal polar angles. Because it's easier I have assumed the former.
When you want n points from the original numsides you can simply map numbers and interpolate:
0 ... n
0 ... numsides

Thus, your (floating-point) interpolation index comes from multiplying point index by numsides/n. Interpolation is done by extracting integer and fractional parts. A little care must be exercised in the last segment if the final point (as here) doesn't repeat the first.
It works whether n is a multiple of numsides (e.g. n=24) or not (e.g. n=13). However, it looks more natural when it is a whole-number multiple (in which case the interpolation might be done with a simple nested loop instead).
from math import pi, sin
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

perimeter = 30.72
numsides = 8            # number of sides (e.g. 8 -> octagon)
n = 24                  # number of perimeter-interpolated points

# Main polygon
radius = perimeter / ( 2 * numsides * sin( pi / numsides ) )
start = 0.5 / numsides         # or just 0
z = radius * np.exp( 2j * pi * ( np.linspace( 0, 1, numsides, endpoint=False ) + start ) )
x, y = z.real, z.imag
plt.plot( x, y, 'r-' );   plt.plot( [x[-1],x[0]], [y[-1],y[0]], 'r-' )

# Added interpolated points
zp = np.zeros( n, dtype=complex )
for p in range( n ):
    r = p * numsides / n                         # rescaled index
    i = int( r );   f = r - i                    # integer and fractional part
    iplus1 = i + 1 if i < numsides-1 else 0      # end point
    zp[p] = z[i] + f * ( z[iplus1] - z[i] )      # interpolate from vertices
xp, yp = zp.real, zp.imag

plt.plot( xp, yp, 'bx' )
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()



If you want the points evenly spaced along the perimeter, you can calculate the length of the perimeter = n * side for an n-sided polygon, distribute the pts points along that total length (totalpos = perimeter * i / pts, where i = 0 ... pts-1), and then walk over the edges, calculating the index of the current side as index = floor(totalpos / side), and the position inside the given side as sidepos = totalpos - index * side. Then take the side in question, and use this internal position along it to get a point.
This JavaScript code does it in an interactive way, the only tricky part is that I wanted to have the bottom-most edge horizontal, that's why the "traditional" x-cos, y-sin are swapped and also offset by a half (this way the length of the side is just the difference of x coordinates). I can't write it in Python at the moment.


function doThing() {
  const n = document.getElementById("ply").valueAsNumber;
  const pts = document.getElementById("pts").valueAsNumber;
  const cnv = document.getElementById("cnv");
  const points = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    points.push([
      cnv.width / 2 * (1 + 0.9 * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * (i - 0.5) / n)),
      cnv.height / 2 * (1 + 0.9 * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * (i - 0.5) / n))
    ]);
  }
  const side = points[1][0] - points[0][0];
  const perimeter = side * n;
  const ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(...points[n - 1]);
  for (const point of points)
    ctx.lineTo(...point);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  for (let i = 0; i < pts; i++) {
    const totalpos = perimeter * i / pts;
    const index = Math.floor(totalpos / side);
    const sidepos = totalpos - index * side;
    const p1 = points[index];
    const p2 = points[(index + 1) % n];
    ctx.fillRect(p1[0] + (p2[0] - p1[0]) * sidepos / side - 2, p1[1] + (p2[1] - p1[1]) * sidepos / side - 2, 5, 5);
  }
}

doThing();
Poly: <input id="ply" type="range" min="3" max="42" value="8" oninput="doThing()"><br>
        Points: <input id="pts" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="10" oninput="doThing()"><br>
<canvas id="cnv" width="400" height="400"></canvas>




One "old school" solution without using external libraries (except to compute cos and sin!):
N = 8  # number of sides of the polygon
R = 5.0172  # radius of the circle containing the polygon
N_points = 12  # number of equally spaced points along the perimeter
PI = 3.14159265

L1 = (perimeter / N)  # length of each polygon side
perimeter = 2 * N * R * np.sin(np.pi / N)
res_coor = []  # coordinates of the N_points points

# Coordinates of the polygons points (last point = first point)
x = [R * np.cos(k * 2 * PI / N) for k in range(N+1)]
y = [R * np.sin(k * 2 * PI / N) for k in range(N+1)]
coor = list(zip(x, y))

def coordinates2D(xA, yA, xB, yB, d):
    """ Gives the coordinates of a point M on a segment [AB] 
    with M located at a distance d from A.
    With vector notation: OM = OA + AM = OA + (d/L1) * AB
    """
    return xA + d / L1 * (xB - xA), yA + d / L1 * (yB - yA)
    
def points_on_side(distances): 
    """For each point, get the distance from the origin of
    the side where it is located."""
    res = []  
    side = [x // L1 + 1 for x in distances]  # N° of the side where is each point
    for i in range(len(distances)): 
        res.append((int(side[i]),  distances[i] - (side[i] - 1) * L1))
    return res  # stores (side n° i, d_i) in a list

# Distances along the perimeter of each point (from the 1st polygon point)
distances = [k * (perimeter / N_points) for k in range(N_points)]

# List of (side n° i, distance from start of side) for each point
points_on_segment = points_on_side(distances)

# Get the 2D coordinates
for i in range(N_points):
    side = points_on_segment[i][0]  # side n°
    res_coor.append(coordinates2D(coor[side-1][0], coor[side-1][1], # xA, yA
                                  coor[side][0], coor[side][1],     # xB, yB
                                  points_on_segment[i][1]))         # d
res_x, res_y = zip(*res_coor)

_, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.scatter(x= res_x, y=res_y, color="g")
plt.show()



Finding evenly spaced points along a polygon using complex numbers
We can use complex numbers to work with rotations. Knowing the perimeter, we calculate other required parameters as follows:
from math import pi, sin, cos

perimeter = 30.72
vertices = 8
angle = 2*pi/vertices
rotation = complex(cos(angle), sin(angle))
edge = perimeter/vertices
radius = 0.5*edge/sin(0.5*angle)
polygon = [radius*rotation**i for i in range(vertices+1)]

Here, we build the octagon vertices in the complex plane using the complex number rotation, which is a unit vector whose exponentiation models a rotation.
When looking for a point at a given distance along the perimeter from the starting vertex, we can determine the pair of polygon vertices the point lies between and calculate the offset from the first one in this pair using divmod:
index, shift = divmod(distance, edge)

Here, index specifies the vertex just beyond which the point is located, and shift is the distance from this vertex. To find the point in the complex plane, we interpret complex numbers as vectors (note that edge represents the distance between adjacent vertices):
polygon[index] + (polygon[index+1]-polygon[index])*shift/edge

Therefore, we can find n evenly spaced points along the octagon perimeter as follows:
linspace = (divmod(perimeter*i/n, edge) for i in range(n))
linspace = (polygon[i:=int(index)] + (polygon[i+1] - polygon[i])*shift/edge 
            for index, shift in linspace)
linspace = [(x.real, x.imag) for x in linspace]

Generalization for any polygon:
def get_polygonal_linspace(n:int, vertices:int, *, radius=1, perimeter=None, return_polygon=False):
    from math import pi, sin, cos
    angle = 2*pi/vertices
    rotation = complex(cos(angle), sin(angle))
    if perimeter is None:
        edge = 2*radius*sin(0.5*angle)
        perimeter = edge*vertices
    else:
        edge = perimeter/vertices
        radius = 0.5*edge/sin(0.5*angle)
    polygon = [radius*rotation**i for i in range(vertices+1)]
    linspace = (divmod(perimeter*i/n, edge) for i in range(n))
    linspace = (polygon[i:=int(index)] + (polygon[i+1] - polygon[i])*shift/edge 
                for index, shift in linspace)
    linspace = [(x.real, x.imag) for x in linspace]
    if return_polygon:
        return linspace, [(x.real, x.imag) for x in polygon] 
    return linspace

Let's visualize:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

linspace, polygon = get_polygonal_linspace(10, vertices=8, perimeter=30.72,
                                           return_polygon=True)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.plot(*zip(*polygon), c='YellowGreen')
plt.scatter(*zip(*linspace), c='DarkGreen')


P.S. I highly recommend watching the episode about complex numbers by 3Blue1Brown.
